intersection of a set of lines what method should be preferred?
I have a set of lines given by their equations a * x + b * y + c = 0
where a b and c are respectively in the first, second and third column of array ALines
array([[ 1.70264755e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -1.63411657e+02],
   [ 1.81980583e-01, -1.00000000e+00, -7.61116889e+01],
   [ 1.91616985e-01, -1.00000000e+00,  2.15926535e+01],
   [ 1.97418713e-01, -1.00000000e+00,  1.30115477e+02],
   [ 2.25261057e-01, -1.00000000e+00,  6.38130206e+02],
   [ 2.29732905e-01, -1.00000000e+00,  8.04003318e+02]])

These lines correspond to parallel lines on the ground projected on to an image
Then I implemented two methods:
least square np.linalg.lstsq(ALines[:,:2],-ALines[:,2])
which lead to the point
[x,y] = [-16601.95191384,  -3084.36361605]
and
U, S, Vh = np.linalg.svd(ALines)
with the last singular value being the smallest one and the corresponding vector
vh[-1]= [-9.83102104e-01, -1.83058050e-01,  5.73922845e-05]
And then to get a point in projective space
Vh[-1] / Vh[-1,-1] = [-1.71295168e+04, -3.18959336e+03,  1.00000000e+00]
then [x,y] = = [-1.71295168e+04, -3.18959336e+03]
which is not the same point as the one obtained using least squares
Then I do not get the same point. Several books mention the last method.
Can anyone explain why one method should be preferred?

Hi. Welcome. I'm writing to help you improve your question, so that you can get a more useful response. (1) Clarify! "Then I implemented two methods": two methods for doing what?  Try to read your question as if you were one of us, who have no idea what you're talking about. (2) Prettify: Do your best to use the "{}" icon to format anything that's computer code or computer output so that it's more readable.

Are you looking for a "most realistic" point of intersection of lines that do not concur (in a common point) ?

If such is the case, see this question and its answers.
